# Income tax what to do

Tags: taxes, canada, income

My job is being abolished my total income for this year will be 128,000; 71,000 of that is severance. I am able to defer some money until next year to avoid tax. So I have like 50,000 that I would defer, or would it be better to put it in an RRSP? Either way, I will need to access that money next year to pay off debts. What is the better way to go?

Answer (score 1):

We need more info to give a better answer, but in short: if you assume you will make $0 in other employment income next year, there is a HUGE tax benefit in deferring 50k until next year. Total tax savings would probably be something like $15k [rough estimate]. If you took the RRSP deduction this year, you would save something like 20k this year, but then you would be taxed on it next year if you withdraw it, probably paying another 5k the year after. ie: you would get about the same net tax savings in both years, if you contributed to your RRSP and withdrew next year, vs deferring it to next year.

On a non-tax basis, you would benefit by having the cash today, so you could earn investment income on your RRSP, but you would want to go low-risk as you need the money next year, so the most you could earn would be something like 1.5k @ 3%.

The real benefit to the RRSP contribution is if you defer your withdrawal into your retirement, because you can further defer your taxes into the future, earning investment income in the meantime. But if you need to withdraw next year, you won't get that opportunity.